# Proportion vs. Number of Female Professors

Tags: probability

I have the following problem, where I am asked to consider two universities $H$ and $Y$, each having $100$ professors.  Construct an example where, in each of the categories "assistant professors", "associate professors", and "full professors", the proportion who are women is higher at $H$ than at $Y$ and yet $Y$ has more female professors than $H$.

It seems that there must be a fourth category (e.g. adjunct), at least at Y and possibly at H.  If not, then take $x_1$ and $y_1$ to be the number of assistant professors at H and Y respectively, $x_2$ and $y_2$ to be the number of associate professors, and $x_3$ and $y_3$ to be the number of full professors.  If $\frac{x_1}{100} \gt \frac{y_1}{100}, \frac{x_2}{100} \gt \frac{y_2}{100}, \textrm{and} \frac{x_3}{100} \gt \frac{y_3}{100}$, then $\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{100} \gt \frac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{100}$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3 \gt y_1+y_2+y_3$.  Can someone corroborate or refute this line of argument?

Comment: Your way of modeling the problem is incorrect; the proportion of female assistant professors at H, for instance, is $\frac{x_{1f}}{x_1}$, not $\frac{x_1}{100}$.  As strange as this result seems, it is possible; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox for details and an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say $Y$ has $98$ full professors, $45$ of which are women.  $H$ has two full professors, with one woman.

$Y$ has one professor of each other type, no women.

$H$ has $49$ professors of each other type, and $1$ women associate and one woman assistant.

Then what $H$ has a higher percentage at each level.

But overall, $Y$ has $100$ professors, $45$ of them women. $H$ has $100$ professors, and a mere $3$ of them women.

The overall percentage is a weighted average of the percentages at each level. But the weights are in proportion to the number of professors of each type. So we can make the overall average be close to the "best" percentage for $Y$, while make the overall percentage be close to the worst percentage for $H$.